# Login is not happening, getting again login page even if i enter correct details

Tags: php, mysql

Login is not taking place and I am being returned to the same page. When I give the correct details I am being returned to the login again and when I give the wrong details I am getting the message of invalid email or password.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    session_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // username and password sent from Form 
        $email=addslashes($_POST['email']); 
        $password=addslashes($_POST['password']); 

        $sql="SELECT id FROM register WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";

        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $active=$row['active'];
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "$count";
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1)
        {
            echo "hi";
            session_register("email");
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$email;

            header("location: welcome.php");
        }
        else 
        {
            $error="Your email or Password is invalid";
            echo "$error";
        }
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="email" name="email"/><br />
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>
```

Comment: What is `$count` echo'ing??? and it should just be `echo $count` no need to put quotes

Comment: Sidenote: Don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: $COUNT IS ECHOING 0 IF I AM ENTERING WRONG PAASSWORD , BUT IF I AM GIVING CORRECT ONE THEN ITS NOT AT ALL ECHOING AND SIMPLE LOGIN FORM IS VISIBLE

Comment: Your code shows different, it says it will echo `$count` no matter what before it checks to see if the row count is 1

Comment: Looks like you spilled some coffee on your CAPS lock or SHIFT key. If not, stop "shouting". @user3477265 Letters in CAPS is considered as shouting.

Comment: YEAH , IT IS ADDED TO CHECK WHETHER I AM GETTING 1 OR 0 ,

Comment: It is going to be hard to diagnose the problem when you are not answering. Did you get a 1 or a 0 when you ran your script. The error message will only show if you get a 0

Comment: if i am entering wrong email or password i am getting count as 0 , but if i am entering correct details  it is not printing the count value nor it is going to the welcome.php page

Comment: You are only selecting the id column (`"SELECT id FROM register`), so the statement `$active=$row['active'];` is not going to work.

Comment: @user3477265 What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @user3477265 You can check your version of PHP by adding `phpinfo();` to this script - the version will appear right at the top of the output.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

`The PHP directive magic_quotes_gpc was on by default before PHP 5.4, and it essentially ran addslashes() on all GET, POST, and COOKIE data. Do not use addslashes() on strings that have already been escaped with magic_quotes_gpc as you'll then do double escaping.`

So those inputs are now being double-escaped. You can call the function [get_magic_quotes_gpc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) to find out what the current settings are and know for certain.